# uitableviewcell not showing swift 3

Tags: uitableview, swift3

I'm working on a swift assignment about table view controller and my table view doesn't have anything on it. I have correctly connected the labels and classes and assigned tableview cell identifier as "cell" in the attribute on storyboard but I still have the error "need to register nib" and even if I wrote `self.tableView.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")` the error is gone but there's still nothing on it.

My cell class is as below.

```
class cartTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var itemImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var itemName: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var itemQuan: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var itemFrame: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var itemSize: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var itemPrice: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var itemSub: UILabel!

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}`
```

my function is

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"Cell", for: indexPath) as! cartTableViewCell

    let item = itemArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.itemName?.text = item.itemName!
    cell.itemFrame?.text = "haha"//itemArray[indexPath.row].itemFrame!
    cell.itemSize?.text = item.itemSize!
    cell.itemPrice?.text = item.sellingPrice!
    //cell.itemQuan?.text =
    cell.itemSub?.text = "\(Int(item.sellingNumber!)! * Int(item.sellingPrice!)!)"
    return cell
}`
```

If I print(item.itemName), I can get some value. `cell.itemName?.text` is nil

I checked some answers online but so far no luck. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Remove code

```
self.tableView.register(TableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
```

Write below code in cartTableViewCell

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
            super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
            // code common to all your cells goes here
        }

        required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
            super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        }
```

Now modify your code with below code

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"Cell", for: indexPath) as! cartTableViewCell
    if cell == nil {
            cell = cartTableViewCell.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        }
    let item = itemArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.itemName?.text = item.itemName!
    cell.itemFrame?.text = "haha"//itemArray[indexPath.row].itemFrame!
    cell.itemSize?.text = item.itemSize!
    cell.itemPrice?.text = item.sellingPrice!
    //cell.itemQuan?.text =
    cell.itemSub?.text = "\(Int(item.sellingNumber!)! * Int(item.sellingPrice!)!)"
    return cell
}
```

Comment: @Irene Z start with capital letter when you declare class name

Answer (score 0):

Just check the **reuse identifier** name in your code. I am just writing this for more explanation.

```
viewDidLoad(){
            let customNib = UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: Bundle.main)
            tableView.register(customNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")
        }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
   cell.configureCell(text: data[indexPath.row])
}
```

**Never do this :**

```
let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:"Cell", for: indexPath) as! cartTableViewCell
        if cell == nil {
                cell = cartTableViewCell.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
            }
```

**Explantion :**

> A UITableViewCell object with the associated reuse identifier. This
>   method always returns a valid cell. Ref:https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614878-dequeuereusablecell.

Answer (score 0):

Do this, I just got this error today and I got it fixed by :

```
let yourNib = UINib(nibName: "yourNibName", bundle: Bundle.main)
yourTableView.register(yourNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
```